# iPhone/Objective-c - Gaining access to a previous ViewController from a subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

How do I access a previous view controller while in a subview? Because I'm able to perform actions but I'm just not able to use `self.[my main view controller]`.

This is my code, for testing purposes:

PhotoViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)likeButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //this part works
    NSString *num = @"2";
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@",
                                                 self.label.text,
                                                 num];

    //this part doesn't work
    //switch over to the third view to see if it worked
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I have a `UITabBarController` and one of its view controllers has a `UIScrollView`. Inside of the `UIScrollView` is a `PhotoViewController` object.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch
    MyTabBarViewController *vc2 = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *vc3 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    controller = [[DemoAppViewController alloc] init];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);

    controller.title = @"Intro Screen";
    vc2.title = @"Explore";
    vc3.title = @"Send a Pic";
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller, vc2, vc3, nil];
    [controller release];
    [vc2 release];
    [vc3 release];

    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;

}
```

Also, my TabBarViewController.m //not my actual UITabBarController though, wording is confusing

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    arrayCount = [array count];
    scroller.delegate=self;
    scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

    //should have an array of photo objects and the number of objects, correct?
    scrollWidth = 0;
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(arrayCount*scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount;i++) {
        PhotoViewController *pvc = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];        
        UIImageView *scrollImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(scroller.bounds, scrollWidth, 0)];
        CGRect rect = scrollImageView.frame;
        pvc.view.frame  = rect;
        pvc.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        id individualPhoto = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",individualPhoto);
        NSArray *keys=[individualPhoto allKeys];
        NSLog(@"%@",keys);
        NSString *imageURL=[individualPhoto objectForKey:@"source"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        pvc.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        pvc.label.text = [individualPhoto objectForKey:@"id"];
        [scroller addSubview:pvc.view];
        [scrollImageView release];
        //[pvc release];
        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }

    if (arrayCount > 3) {
        pageControl.numberOfPages=3;
    } else {
    pageControl.numberOfPages=arrayCount;
    }
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
}
```

Comment: you got two ways, set a property in your app delegate, or pass a reference pointing to the tab controller to the concerned subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining this method in your `PhotoViewController`:

```
+ (YOURTABBARCONTROLLER*)parentTabBarController:(UIResponder*)view {
    id nextResponder = nil;
    id v = view;
    while (nextResponder = [v nextResponder]) {
               NSLog(@"Found Responder: %@", nextResponder); //-- ADDED THIS
       if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[YOURTABBARCONTROLLER class]])
          return nextResponder;
        v = nextResponder;
    }
    return nil;
 }
```

it will traverse the responder chain and return the first controller of a given type that is found. Replace `YOURTABBARCONTROLLER` with your actual tab bar controller class and you should be able to have:

```
-(IBAction)likeButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //this part works
    NSString *num = @"2";
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@",
                                             self.label.text,
                                             num];

    [PhotoViewController parentTabBarController:self.view].selectedIndex = 0;
    // self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

---

Updated

```
-(IBAction)likeCommentButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //code goes here
    TypeSomethingViewController *typeSomethingViewController = [[TypeSomethingViewController alloc] init];
    typeSomethingViewController.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:typeSomethingViewController animated:YES];
    [typeSomethingViewController release];
}

-(void)typeSomethingViewController:(TypeSomethingViewController *)controller didTypeSomething:(NSString *)text
{
    //NSLog(@"response: %@", controller);

    NSString *commentID = self.label.text;
    for(UIViewController *controller in [PhotoViewController parentTabBarController:self.parentViewController.view].viewControllers)
    {
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[DemoAppViewController class]])
        {
            DemoAppViewController *davc = (DemoAppViewController *)controller;
            //[davc commentPicture:commentID :message];
            [davc likePicture:commentID];
        }
    }
    [PhotoViewController parentTabBarController:self.view].selectedIndex = 0;

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Hi @sergio ... I tried replacing YOURTABBARCONTROLLER with tbc, MyTabBarController and UITabBarController but none of them worked. I added more of my code to show how the ViewControllers are added. Thank you for the feedback :-)

Comment: Would you add the NSLog statement as above and tell me what is the output on the console?

Comment: should I be using tbc, MyTabBarController or UITabBarController for to test the above? I can try all three

Comment: also, does while `(nextResponder = [v nextResponder])` need 2 equal signs? while `(nextResponder == [v nextResponder])` ... I received a warning

Comment: for the test is not relevant what you use. you can remove the warning by writing: ` while ((nextResponder = [v nextResponder])) {` (note the doubled parenthesis, single = is what I mean here).

Comment: I don't think it returned anything, there weren't any errors (I'm looking at the debug area at the bottom of Xcode)

Comment: Are you sure you are calling that method to get the parent controller? something like: `[PhotoViewController parentTabBarController:self.view];`

Comment: 2011-07-11 15:32:24.738 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <PhotoViewController: 0x5a70a40>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.823 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <UIScrollView: 0x5a72140; frame = (0 0; 320 411); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5a72380>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.824 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <UIView: 0x5a71160; frame = (0 0; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5a711b0>>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.825 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder:

Comment: <MyTabBarViewController: 0x5a1efd0>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.826 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x5a71450; frame = (0 20; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5a722e0>>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.827 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <UITransitionView: 0x5a326c0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5a32760>>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.828 DemoApp[4996:207] Found Responder: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x5a32020; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5a320c0>>
2011-07-11 15:32:24.829 DemoApp[4996:207]

Comment: Found Responder: <UITabBarController: 0x5a31c60>

Comment: ok, so you can actually find all the controllers you need... decide which one and then have a look at my edit for integration with your code...

Comment: Very cool. That worked! :-) Thank you @Sergio ... btw, is there a way to mark two answers correctly? Because both you and Vince's answer worked

Comment: Hi @Sergio - I've added a modal viewcontroller to my PhotoViewController ... can your method of traversing the responder chain still work?

Comment: Actually, I don't know... I think the modal view controller should be found in the responder chain somewhere, so it should work... if you have problems, use the logs as the the other day, so you know what is there...

Comment: Ah I see. It only found PhotoViewController, as opposed to the rest of the responders. Do I need to use that and search for responders again using the code snippets from yesterday? Here is the modal view response data - `2011-07-12 13:49:13.042 DemoApp[1457:207] response: <TypeSomethingViewController: 0x5a36fd0>
2011-07-12 13:49:13.043 DemoApp[1457:207] Found Responder: <PhotoViewController: 0x5a5fc50>
2011-07-12 13:49:13.044 DemoApp[1457:207] Found Responder: <PhotoViewController: 0x5a5fc50>`

Comment: It may well be that for modal views, the responder chain has only got the immediate parent... so, call that method on PhotoViewController, it is a class method...

Comment: what method? I updated your previous answer to show you what I'm trying to do. could you clarify what method you're talking about?

Comment: the method I meant is `parentTabBarController`. I think that it should work how you are doing... does it work?

Comment: no, still not working. I even tried adding a `+ (MYUIVIEWCONTROLLER*)parentUIViewController:(UIResponder*)view` method and using `for(UIViewController *controller in [PhotoViewController parent TabBarController:[PhotoViewController parentUIViewController:self.parentViewController.view].viewControllers)`

Comment: Solved it via a workaround. Created a UITabBarController (tempController) variable in the header file. When the user clicks on the button I set `tempController = [PhotoViewController parentTabBarController:self.view];` from there I can just substitute it in :-) Thanks again for your all your help @Sergio

Answer (score 3):

If a UIView subclass needs to message a controller above itself, a common (and often recommended?) way to do this is to have the view subclass implement the delegate protocol (a weak linked instance variable pointing to the view controller that you want to use). The view controller should then set itself as the delegate of the view when that view is being initialize.

Comment: +1 Thank you for a sane answer. The OP SHOULD NOT be referencing the the tab bar from within a view, and recommending to access the value from the App Delegate is even worse.

Comment: Thank you @hotpaw2 and @joe ... @joe could you give some feedback on all the answers provided? (i.e., really short pros and cons) Because I received a couple of solutions that work but I'm not sure what the "proper" way is

Comment: Your view should not access any view controller directly. Think about how a UIButton works, all it does is tell you that the user touched up and cares nothing about any view controllers. Your view should do the same just reporting back when an action is performed. The view controller that responds to your views action could then access its tabbar and set the selectedIndex.

Comment: I'm confused. I might have worded the question incorrectly. I have the view of a UIViewController, the UIViewController is called PhotoViewController. This view is in another UIViewController called MyTabBarViewController. The code for performing an action is in PhotoViewController and I want it to affect MyTabBarViewController. I thought VCs could talk to one another etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to switch to the first controller.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController 
= [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Change the index value to switch to whichever controller you want to switch to.

Comment: hi @Vidyanand - i tried but it didn't do anything. I don't think self.tabBarController.[anything i want to put here] will work ...

Comment: You might want to add a little more context on how you add your ViewControllers to the TabBarController. What I mentioned is the programmatic way to do this according to the official docs for iOS. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Vidyanand - I added more code for context.

Comment: IN your case PhotoViewController is not one of those controllers you have added to the tabbar. Hence self.tabBarController will not be valid since PhotoViewController does not have a UITabBarcontroller. I would try and see if the parentcontroller has the UITabBarController . Something like this self.parentViewController.tabBarController.

Comment: I tried `self.parentViewController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;` which is valid - but didn't do anything ... I was hoping that would work though :-)

Comment: I don't believe setting selectedIndex is the preferred method. You are to do this rather self.parentViewController. tabBarController.selectedViewController 
= [self.parentViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Just to be sure try printing out what the class of the parentController is. So try something like this if( [self.parentViewController. isKindOfClass:[TabBarViewController class]] )

Comment: I tried `if( [self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[MyTabBarViewController class]] ) {
        NSString *num = @"2";
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@", self.label.text, num];
    }` and also `if( [self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]] ) {
        NSString *num = @"2";
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ + %@", self.label.text, num];
    }` but they didn't do anything. I wasn't able to try `TabBarViewController` (unknown receiver)

Answer (score 0):

The `tabBarController` should be a property of the app delegate.

Try accessing it with :

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                               delegate];
appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Unless you declare the same property in `PhotoViewController`, you won't be able to access it this way.

Try importing the app delegate header in PhotoViewController.h like so :

```
#import "MyAppDelegate"
```

then try this code above replacing `tabBarController` by `tbc` which, as the example suggests is the name given to this property.

Comment: I think I might need to set the tabBarController as a property of the app delegate because right now it your suggestion only returns "returns "Property 'tabBarController' not found on object of type '[AppDelegate name]'" ... I've updated my question with more code for more context. Do you recommend that I do a @property for my tabBarController?

Comment: Yes declare a property for tbc, which hosts your tabbed view controllers. I edited my answer too

Comment: this worked :-) thanks @Vince ... I'm going to continue trying out some of the other suggestions to see if those also work. Thank you again.